# Use SliverGrid inside SliverList

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting error of

> A RenderRepaintBoundary expected a child of type RenderBox but received a child of type RenderSliverGrid.

I'd like to build a grid of items but I am getting the above mentioned error. My code having `SliverGrid` is in `CollectionCard`. Below I have pasted some part of the code related to SliverGrid. The code works if I cut the SliverGrid part of the code and then paste it directly inside `slivers[]` but I need to use where it is currently.

```
return CustomScrollView(
  controller: controller,
  keyboardDismissBehavior: ScrollViewKeyboardDismissBehavior.onDrag,
  slivers: [
    const HomeSliverList(),
  ],
);
```

**HomeSliverList Class**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return SliverList(
  delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
    [
      CollectionCard(),
      SizedBox(
        height: 16.h,
      ),
      TextCard(),
    ],
  ),
);
```

}

**CollectionCard Class with SliverGrid**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return ImageCard(
  child: SliverGrid(
      gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 2, mainAxisSpacing: 0, crossAxisSpacing: 0),
      delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(List.generate(
          10,
          (index) => Container(
                height: 50,
                child: Text('Hello'),
              )))),
);}
```

**ImageCard Class**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  width: double.infinity,
  margin: kPagePadding,
  padding: kCardPadding,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: kCardBorderRadius,
    color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
  ),
  child: child,
);}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Container` isn't a sliver widget that has been returning from `CollectionCard`. For current snippet, you can place only SliverGrid directly inside `CustomScrollView(slivers:[...here...]`

```dart
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: [
    SliverList(),  
    SliverGrid(),
```

You can use Rows/Column combination for your purpose, or use `GridView` but parent widget(CustomScrolView) is already handling scrolling. `shrinkWrap: true,` (`physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()`) will solve the issue

```dart
  GridView.count(
    crossAxisCount: 2,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    // physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    children:
```

But better option will be using SliverGrid directly inside `Slivers` depends your purpose

Comment: GridView.count worked, thank you for the help